# Angular Deleting Issue

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular, spring-boot

i've been stuck in an error for such a time and i don't know how to solve it.
I am trying to delete but the content cannot be deleted, i'll show my code. Currently i'm using Angular and Spring Boot.

**The error i'm getting: zone.js:2680          DELETE http://localhost:8080/produtos-inseridos/ 405**

**Template:**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form
      method="post"
      [formGroup]="myForm"
      (ngSubmit)="gravar()"
    >
      <table class="table p-3" method="post">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cód.</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Unidade</th>
            <th scope="col">Qtd. Estocada</th>
            <th scope="col">Qtd. Reservada</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
            <td>
              <input
                type="hidden"
                name="codProduto"
                formControlName="codProduto"
              />{{ produto.codProduto }}
            </td>
            <td>{{ produto.nome }}</td>
            <td>{{ produto.unidade }}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="hidden"
                name="qtdEstocada"
                formControlName="qtdEstocada"
              />{{ produto.qtdEstocada }}
            </td>
            <td>{{ produto.qtdReservada }}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" formControlName="id" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1"
                (click)="deleteProduto(produtos)"
              >
                Deletar
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-success col-sm-1 p-2"
        (click)="gravar()"
      >
        Gravar
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #deleteModal>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p>Tem certeza que deseja remover este produto?</p>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-default"
      (click)="confirmDelete($event)"
    >
      Sim
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="declineDelete()">
      Não
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Ts Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabela-produtos-inseridos',
  templateUrl: './tabela-produtos-inseridos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabela-produtos-inseridos.component.scss'],
})
export class TabelaProdutosInseridosComponent implements OnInit {
  produtos: ProdutosInseridos[] = [];
  @ViewChild('deleteModal') deleteModal: any;
  message?: string;
  @Input() produtoSelecionado: ProdutosInseridos[] = [];
  public myForm!: FormGroup;
  deleteModalRef?: BsModalRef;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private produtosInseridosService: ProdutosInseridosService,
    private gravarProdutoService: GravarProdutosService,
    private router: Router,
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.myForm = new FormGroup({
       id: new FormControl(['', [Validators.required]]),
       codProduto: new FormControl(['', [Validators.required]]),
       qtdEstocada: new FormControl(['', [Validators.required]]),
     });

    this.produtosInseridosService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe((dados) => (this.produtos = dados));
    this.produtosInseridosService.deleteProduto;
  }

  gravar() {
       let gravar = this.gravarProdutoService.updateProduto(this.myForm.value).subscribe(() => {
          (result: any) => result;
          (response: any) => {
            this.produtos = response;
          };
        });

        console.log(gravar);

    this.router.navigate(['/form']);
     this.myForm.reset();
  }

  deleteProduto(produto: ProdutosInseridos[]) {
    this.produtoSelecionado = produto;
    this.deleteModalRef = this.modalService.show(this.deleteModal, {
      class: 'modal-sm',
    });
  }

  //ajeitar o delete
  confirmDelete(id: any) {
    this.produtosInseridosService
      .deleteProduto(this.produtoSelecionado.filter((x) => x.id == id))
      .subscribe(
        (success) => {
          alert('Produto deletado com sucesso' + success);
          this.deleteModalRef?.hide();
        },
        (error) => {
          alert('Não foi possível deletar o produto. Tente mais tarde' + error);
          this.deleteModalRef?.hide();
        }
      );

    this.message = 'Confirmed!';
  }

  declineDelete(): void {
    this.message = 'Declined!';
    this.deleteModalRef?.hide();
  }
}
```

**API Controler**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("quantidades")
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class QuantidadeController {
    @Autowired
    private final DateUtil dateUtil;
    private final QuantidadeRepository quantidadeRepository;
    private final QuantidadeService quantidadeService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<QuantidadeEntity>> list(){
        log.info(dateUtil.formatLocalTimeToDatabaseStyle(LocalDateTime.now()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(quantidadeService.listAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = {"/id"})
    public ResponseEntity<QuantidadeEntity> findById(@PathVariable int id){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(quantidadeService.findbyidOrThrowBadRequestException(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<QuantidadeEntity> save(@RequestBody QuantidadePostRequestBody quantidadePostRequestBody) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(quantidadeService.save(quantidadePostRequestBody), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        quantidadeService.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<QuantidadeEntity> Put(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id, @RequestBody QuantidadePutRequestBody quantidadePutRequestBody) {
        Optional<QuantidadeEntity> antigaQuantidade = quantidadeRepository.findById(id);

        if(antigaQuantidade.isPresent()){
            QuantidadeEntity quantidade = antigaQuantidade.get();
            quantidade.setQuantidade(quantidadePutRequestBody.getQuantidade());

            quantidadeRepository.save(quantidade);
            return new ResponseEntity<QuantidadeEntity>(quantidade, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello, add detail about the "produtosInseridosService" to see what are you doing there. I guess you are doing bad calling the method delete defined in your controller.

Comment: The question is not clear, it said delete is not working, we need to what exatrly not working.